# Plot group bar charts with matplotlib or Seaborn with Datetime Index in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Pandas DataFrame that consists of a date column and a category column of interest. I would like to see the Frequency count for each month. When I did this with matplotlib, I get something that looks quite bad.

Here is what the frame looks like when grouped by the months:

```
df.resample("M")["category_col"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)

Output

date                         category_col      
2019-12-31  A                41.929004
            B                25.758765
            C                17.752111
            D                9.189919
            E                3.625122
            F                1.745080
2020-01-31  A                54.052744
            C                16.347271
            B                14.414431
            D                11.677537
            E                2.675607
            F                0.832411
2020-02-29  A                48.928468
            D                22.011116
            C                14.084507
            C                11.729162
            E                2.193272
            F                1.053475
2020-03-31  A                54.435410
            D                15.718065
            C                14.577060
            B                11.335682
            E                2.884205
            F                1.049578
Name: category_col, dtype: float64
```

Here what my attempt

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df.resample("M")["category_col"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).plot(kind="bar")
```

See the output below:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with `rename` for rormat of datetimes `month name year`:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index("date")

s = df.resample("M")["category_col"].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)

s.unstack().rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%B %Y')).plot(kind="bar")
```

Sample:

```
print (s)
date        category_col
2019-12-31  A               41.929004
            B               25.758765
            C               17.752111
            D                9.189919
            E                3.625122
            F                1.745080
2020-01-31  A               54.052744
            C               16.347271
            B               14.414431
            D               11.677537
            E                2.675607
            F                0.832411
2020-02-29  A               48.928468
            B               22.011116
            C               14.084507
            D               11.729162
            E                2.193272
            F                1.053475
2020-03-31  A               54.435410
            D               15.718065
            C               14.577060
            B               11.335682
            E                2.884205
            F                1.049578
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (s.unstack())
category_col          A          B          C          D         E         F
date                                                                        
2019-12-31    41.929004  25.758765  17.752111   9.189919  3.625122  1.745080
2020-01-31    54.052744  14.414431  16.347271  11.677537  2.675607  0.832411
2020-02-29    48.928468  22.011116  14.084507  11.729162  2.193272  1.053475
2020-03-31    54.435410  11.335682  14.577060  15.718065  2.884205  1.049578
```

---

```
print (s.unstack().rename(lambda x: x.strftime('%B %Y')))
category_col           A          B          C          D         E         F
date                                                                         
December 2019  41.929004  25.758765  17.752111   9.189919  3.625122  1.745080
January 2020   54.052744  14.414431  16.347271  11.677537  2.675607  0.832411
February 2020  48.928468  22.011116  14.084507  11.729162  2.193272  1.053475
March 2020     54.435410  11.335682  14.577060  15.718065  2.884205  1.049578
```

Comment: This works well. but the bars are not sorted and the dates show like 2020-01-31, 2020-02,31. How can I change them to January, February, etc?

Comment: After I did ```import datetime from datetime``` and apply the above, I get the following error: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' ```

Comment: @A.JT - ther eis not lost `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index("date")` ?

Comment: Yes it is a datetime

Comment: @A.JT - What is `print (s.unstack().index)` ?

Comment: ``` MultiIndex([( 'C', '2019-12-31'),
            (       'C', '2020-01-31'),
            (       'C', '2020-02-29'),
            (       'C', '2020-03-31'),
            (          'D', '2019-12-31'),
            (          'D', '2020-01-31'),
            (          'D', '2020-02-29'),
            (          'D', '2020-03-31'),],
           names=['category_col', 'date'])  ```

Comment: @A.JT - there is no lost `unstack()` ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @A.JT - Can you check edited answer? It seems your `s` is different like me.

Comment: is there a way I could have the bar sorted from the highest to the lowest? I have tried different kinds of stuff but ist not sorting from the highest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210430/discussion-between-a-j-t-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to get the name of the months, reset the index and select the right columns:

```
df['month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).strftime('%B'))

df = df.reset_index()

df = df[['month','category_col','value]]
```

Then, assuming that you have a dataframe (called **df**) like this:

```
month       category_col     value      
September   A                41.929004
September   B                25.758765
```

Perform the following to get the plot you are looking for, using Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns 
ax = sns.barplot(x="month", y="value", hue="category_col", data=df)
```